# Trying to make multiple DB connections with singletons pattern for multiple queries

Tags: php

I'm trying to do multiple queries from a class. Each array of objects gets returned to a private _Data var.

The problem is when I do a new query the _data var gets overwritten with new data. What is the best approach to tackle this situation?

```
    public function getDeliveryBy($orderid) {
//ORDER CLASS
    $data = $this->_db->query("SELECT deliveryby FROM order WHERE orderid = $orderid");
    //$data = $this->_db->get('rt_order', array('orderid', '=', $orderid));

    if ($data->count()) {
        $this->_data = $data->first();
        //this returns the orderline...

        $return = '';

        $return .= '<select id="status" class="form-control" name="status">';

        //if in orderline the user is 0 set not set
        if ($this->data()->deliveryby === "0") {
            $return .= '<option value="0" selected>Not set</option>';
        }

        // Now i want to get a list of all employees...

        // get all employees
        //$result = $this->_db->query("SELECT id,username FROM users");

        foreach () {
        //make... mutiple options
        }


        $return .= '</select>';

        return $return;

    }
    return false;

}
```

////UPDATE
What I have done

1. Made a new instance in Class order constructor (for user class)

   ```
   public function __construct() {
   $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
   $this->_employee = new User();
   ```

   }
2. add this in method

   ```
           //Get all employees
       $this->employee()->getAllUsers();
       foreach ($this->employee()->data() as $key=>$employee) {
           echo $employee->firstname, '<BR>';
       }
   ```

Now the private var data still holds order data... and user data holds user data...

The thing was that I had read that its not OK to instance a new class from a other class... That's why I was wondering if this is ok

Comment: I can make a getAllUsers method in the usersclass and use this data in order class? is this a good approach ?

Comment: FYI: singletons are **not** part of OOP paradigm.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with connections and singleton. It is all on how you implement business logic and data layers.

Comment: ok ill change my question and remove the tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done

1. Made a new instance in Class order constructor (for user class)

   ```
   public function __construct() {
   $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
   $this->_employee = new User();
   ```

   }
2. add this in method

   ```
           //Get all employees
       $this->employee()->getAllUsers();
       foreach ($this->employee()->data() as $key=>$employee) {
           echo $employee->firstname, '<BR>';
       }
   ```

now the private var data still holds order data... and user data holds user data...

The thing was that i had read that its not OK to instance a new class from a other class... s